# Whats is the best method to localize an asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, localization

I use .po files to translate my PHP applications.
Is there an equivalent method for translating effectively ASP.net applications?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASP.NET Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa308935.aspx) using [Resource Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx)

Examples:

[Globalization and Localization in .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/Globalization_Localization_in_DotNet_CSharp07032006023510AM/Globalization_Localization_in_DotNet_CSharp.aspx)

[Localization in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2005/08/08/localizingaspnet20.html)

Answer (score 1):

[This link for Resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx) should help you. It gives the standard methodology for localization in ASP.NET.